# Programatically download files from public sharepoint directory

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365api

I want to list and download files from public Sharepoint directory.
I have link in format
`https://xxx.sharepoint.com/:f:/s/site_name/long_id?e=shorter_id`
which redirects to
`https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?cid=some_id&RootFolder=encoded_path&FolderCTID=another_is`

For not public files I'm using [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client) and real account credentials but this library doesn't allow for usage without auth.

As it seems for relative easy task I could use bare REST API but as I'm complete Sharepoint newbie I could use some tip where to start looking.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Python library I mentioned above but it's not working without auth. I tried sending bare request showed in official doc [Working with folders and files with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest) but it also is not working without auth headers.

Comment: Can you please share your code.

Comment: Library I mentioned earlier doesn't have option to work without auth creds. Just out of curiosity I tried passing empty strings instead login / pass but as suspected it didn't work. 

Bare request is like this `http "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('path of directory')"` (I'm using http-pie) and get 403 error with error message suggesting that I need to authorize request.

Comment: duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286911/how-to-retrieve-json-file-via-rest-api-and-download-it-in-sharepoint/74522243#74522243

Comment: @johnktejik did you bother checking dates of questions? :)

Comment: @Banciur I did actually.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be not possible to archive using Sharepoint API's (at least couldn't find how) but it's doable by processing bare requests.
It seems under the hood Sharepoint performs some automatic authorization and perform several redirects attaching authorization cookies.
You just have to use some real `User-Agent` for all requests.

Steps are following:

- GET `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/:f:/s/site_name/long_id?e=shorter_id`
  you will receive 301 to authorization endpoint
- GET `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?e=shorter_id&share=long_id`. This one will setup some cookies and 302 to your destination
- GET `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/Shared%20Documents/path_to_dir?cid=some_id` this one will return real data. You must use auth cookies from previous step.
- In response look for `script` tag with javascript `ListData` object. It will contain structure describing all files. You are interested in `FileRef` attribute.
- GET `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=FileRef` it will download your data. Remember about auth header.

It's less then optimal but works for me.