# How to Retrieve JSON file via REST API and download it in SharePoint?

Tags: json, powershell, rest, sharepoint, powerbi

I am newbie REST API area.

I have an API from network server backup where all backup related info is shared in a JSON format.

I need to extract each of the files and save it in shared directory in SharePoint.

Can I use MS Flow or what would be suitable option without coding in Python or C#. Rather I could use Power Shell.

Purpose of these JSON file is to use later in Power BI as the server is not secure i can not use directly Web URL in Power BI.

Comment: Please add some code example and what exactly the problem is...

Comment: Either should work, if you want to use PowerShell take a look at `Invoke-RestMethod` and if you get stuck update the question with your code and what issues you have.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft documentation on Sharepoint Rest requests is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=http#construct-rest-urls-to-access-sharepoint-resources)

And then like PMental said, you can invoke these request requests in Powershell using the [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3) method